# Having issue with DispatchQueue not working after 3-4 executions in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, dispatch-queue

I have the following code below to show a Message to the user and then disappear. Everything works fine for the first 1 to 3 tries, but anything above that the Message window does not disappear as it did on the previous attempts/required.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingNotice = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showingNotice = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Show Notice")
            })

            if showingNotice {
                FloatingNotice(showingNotice: $showingNotice)
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
    }
}

struct FloatingNotice: View {
    @Binding var showingNotice: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .regular))
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5))
        
            Text("Review added")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.callout)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 5, trailing: 10))
        }
        .background(Color.snackbar.opacity(0.75))
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .transition(.scale)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
                self.showingNotice = false
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I am missing or help figure why it "stops" working after multiple executions?

Comment: Are you using which xCode and iOS version?

Comment: Put a print as the first line in onAppear. Is it being called when you expect?  Add an onAppear to the FloatingNotice in ContentView with a print and see what that does

Comment: @PurveshDodiya Version 14.1 (14B47b)

Comment: It seems to only not disappear for me if I click the button when it is in the middle of the disappearing animation. If I wait for it to fully disappear then press the button again, it works no matter how many times I press it.

Comment: @LouFranco i put in the print statement and after a number of times the print statement didnt print and the message didnt go away!? The solution that purvesh provided did the trick tho!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes `onAppear` will not called so your `self.showingNotice = false` is not getting called. So you can do one thing move your delay block inside the button click it self as below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingNotice = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showingNotice = true
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
                    self.showingNotice = false
                })
            }, label: {
                Text("Show Notice")
            })

            if showingNotice {
                FloatingNotice(showingNotice: $showingNotice)
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
    }
}

struct FloatingNotice: View {
    @Binding var showingNotice: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .regular))
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5))
               
        
            Text("Review added")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.callout)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 5, trailing: 10))
        }
        .background(Color(.red))
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .transition(.scale)
        
    }
}
```